# How can I mutate the json in the following way in javascript

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, object, data-structures

I have been asked in an interview to mutate the array of objects in such a way that the data appears in the following manner

```
    [
  {
    "companyName": "ABC",
    "members": [
      {
        "id": 13121212,
        "firstName": "Ray",
        "lastName": "Fernandis",
        "points": 1800,
        "position": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 13131313,
        "firstName": "Carrie",
        "lastName": "Yoda",
        "points": 1200,
        "position": 2
      }
    ]
  }]
```

and the sample data was given below.

```
    [
  {
    "communityName": "ABC",
    "lastUpdateTimestamp": {
      "date": {
        "year": 2020,
        "month": 10,
        "day": 7
      },
      "time": {
        "hour": 18,
        "minute": 6,
        "second": 5,
        "nano": 536529000
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "listChannelsData": [
        {
          "channelId": 1234,
          "channelName": "BCD",
          "members": [
            {
              "id": 13121212,
              "firstName": "Ray",
              "lastName": "Fernandis",
              "points": 1800,
              "position": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "communityName": "DEF",
    "lastUpdateTimestamp": {
      "date": {
        "year": 2020,
        "month": 10,
        "day": 7
      },
      "time": {
        "hour": 18,
        "minute": 6,
        "second": 21,
        "nano": 47894000
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "listChannelsData": [
        {
          "channelId": 3421,
          "channelName": "GHI",
          "members": [
            {
              "id": 13121212,
              "firstName": "Nicholas",
              "lastName": "Xin",
              "points": 800,
              "position": 2
            },
            {
              "id": 13131313,
              "firstName": "Carrie",
              "lastName": "Yoda",
              "points": 1000,
              "position": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

The agenda for me was to print the derived json from sample json and I could only figure out this much code which was a courtesy of stackoverflow

```
function dictionary(data) {
    var map = {};

    data.forEach(item => {
      if (!Array.isArray(map[item.companyName])) {
        map[item.companyName] = [item.data.listChannelsData];        
      } else {
        map[item.communityName].push(item.data.listChannelsData);
      }
    });

    return map;
}

console.log(dictionary(data));
```

But now when I try to pick up the data for the member using another foreach loop, I'm not able to access the data for members. Can anyone help me with the part where I can successfully access the member array and print the company name along side it

Comment: Your json snippets are incomplete.

Comment: edited @DavidKnipe

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var newArray = []
data.map((item, index) => {
newArray[index] = {companyName : item.communityName}
newArray[index].members = item.data.listChannelsData[0].members
})
```

data is the given data.